# Prevent NextJS `Link` from running when clicked on a given child

Tags: next.js

I have a `Link` component which wraps a `div` with several `children`. I want to prevent `Link` from working when clicked on a specific child. How can I do that?

```
<Link href={"go\to\page"}>
    <div class="flex">
       <span>This child should run link</span>
       ... (more childs that should run link)
       <span>This child should not run link!</span>
    </div>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm more than sure that this question has already been answered here, but still: let's say you don't want that when you click on child span element you don't want it to follow the link, you can put onClick event on it, example :

```
<Link href='/home'>
    <span  onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
        }}>this child will not trigger the  routing from link</span>
    <span>but this one will trigger</span>
</Link>
```

explanation from MDN:

The preventDefault() tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be.
The stopPropagation()  prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases. I